# jQuery and detect position of scroll in realtime

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi there how can I change this algorithm to correct jquery or javascript version?

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (y > 50px)        {
        alert("top visible");$('header').addclass('show');
    } else {
        alert("top invisible");$('header').addclass('hide');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**scrollTop()**](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) returns an integer, representing the number of pixels.

`50px` is not an integer, and it will throw an error.

Instead, change:

```
y > 50px
```

to this:

```
y > 50
```

Also note that `addClass()` has a capital **C**.

---

If you're simply showing and hiding the header, you can use `show()` and `hide()`.  You can then test the visibility to determine if the `alert` should fire or not:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var y = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (y > 50 && !$('header').is(':visible')) {
    alert("top visible");
    $('header').show();
  } 
  else if(y <= 50 && $('header').is(':visible')) {
    alert("top invisible");
    $('header').hide();
  }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nz24oh74/)

Comment: thanks. it there any way to run jquery only once after scroll top or bottom of  50?

Comment: I mean,if I scroll bottom,I get a lot of alert message...once is enough fot me

Answer (score 0):

Use console.log instead of alerts to see whats going on behind the scenes

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (y > 50)        {
        console.log("show");
        $('header').addClass('show').removeClass("hide");
    } else {
        console.log("hide");
        $('header').addClass('hide').removeClass("show");
    }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/hobehi/edit?js,console,output